# Why docker desktop is unable to start docker-backend?

Tags: windows, docker, virtualization, wsl-2, docker-desktop

#### Problem:

I started my system as usual but my docker-desktop doesn't work, WSL doesn't respond to commands and there is a process called "Vmmem" using 25% of my memory. I have tried a bunch of thing but nothing seems to work.

#### System Attributes:

- Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19045.2486)
- docker: 4.15
- WSL:  1.0.3.0

#### More context:

Recently I was having trouble with my docker set up. I have one particular container that was "crashing" the docker. It was not throwing any exception but after some event (that I couldn't find out) all the other container where unreachable any attempt to stop/start another container would result on "Error: 500 failed to respond...". When this happens I usually just restart the system and everything works fine, but today it wasn't the case. I restarted and I noticed that I had the "Vmmem" process already running at 25% (it usually just reaches this point at the end of the day), the docker desktop could not start the docker backend and when I tried running `wsl -l -v` I got no response. I can use some docker commands like `docker -v` but the `docker compose up` doesn't work at all.

#### What I've tried:

- restart the system again (nothing changed, still starting with 25% mem usage)
- deactivating Hyper-V (nothing happened)
- stop/start docker service using `net start/stop <service>` (it gives a response but didn't solve the problem)
- Uninstall docker-desktop (it crashes before even starting the uninstall process)
- Terminate WSL `wsl -t Ubuntu` (got no response from wsl)
- Overwrite installation with Docker 4.16 (it gets stuck on "Preparing for update... / Stopping VM and preparing for update")
- Forcefully kill the "Vmmem" (I've got Access denied error)

#### Edit 1:

I managed to finally install the Docker desktop 4.16 but the problem continues, system starts with 25% Vmmem memory usage and docker desktop is not able to initiate backend.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps that I did to be able to stop "Vmmem" process and install docker desktop again:

- disable Hyper-V
- disable virtualization (BIOS)
- restart system

to this point the "Vmmem" problem was gone

- uninstall docker desktop
- rm all wsl instances
- enable Hyper-V
- enable `hypervisorlaunchtype`
- restart system
- enable virtualization (BIOS)
- install wsl Ubuntu instance
- install Docker Desktop

Maybe some steps listed here are redundant but that is what I did. hope it helps if other people is passing through the same problem

Answer (score 1):

the process Vmeem It represents the memory and CPU consumed by the combination of all the virtual machines running on your Windows PC, there is a possibility that processes are still running on your PC. I recommend you try to launch these commands from the console:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

This will stop all containers and delete them.
If this doesn't work, I recommend you enter your bios settings and disable virtualization, that way those processes will stop, then you can enable it again and try. I wish you luck and I hope this resolves.

Comment: Thank you for the response. no docker command was able to generate output. So I decided to just disable Hyper-V and disable virtualization on BIOS which made the "Vmmem" process stop. After that I did some more steps to be able to install docker desktop again. I'm gonna create a separate answer for this but you really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal of your choice in Administrator mode.

Run `taskkill /f /im wslservice.exe`

The Vmmem task should now have been killed. Restart Docker Desktop to resume work.